# How to get CAPTCHA on an ExactTarget landing page?

Tags: marketing-cloud

How to get CAPTCHA on an ExactTarget landing page?  What is involved?

I see that it is built in for Cloud Pages.  However, I have a current landing page where I need to add CAPTCHA.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what CAPTCHA widget you intend to use. I prefer Google's new reCAPTCHA which doesn't use those awkward challenge-response tests. Instead, it just requires users to click on a button in the widget. It uses advanced risk analysis to consider a user's entire engagement with the CAPTCHA—before, during, and after—to determine whether that user is a human.

Anyway, it appears to work in landing pages. I created a landing page with the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
        <style>
          input {margin-bottom:20px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
           <label>First name</label>
           <input type="text" name="firstname"><br />
           <label>Last name</label>
           <input type="text" name="lastname">
           <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdxZgETAAAAAEm8KeQb3d9opjQzC509m7VFeE4P"></div>
           <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I publish my landing page it appears correctly:

[image: captcha]

I haven't added any [server side code](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) to check the users response, but I'm assuming that this can be implemented by SSJS.